# Rearrange columns in SQLAlchemy Select object

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

#### Question

How can I reorder the columns in a SQLAlchemy query object?

#### Example

Given a SQLAlchemy core `Select` object representing the following query:

```
>>> print s
SELECT sum(accounts.amount) AS amount_sum, accounts.name 
FROM accounts GROUP BY accounts.name
 LIMIT :param_1
```

I want to form the a `Select` object with the exact same structure, but with the order of the columns moved around

```
SELECT accounts.name,  sum(accounts.amount) AS amount_sum
FROM accounts GROUP BY accounts.name
 LIMIT :param_1
```

#### What I've tried that doesn't work

I want to do this without expanding the SQL significantly.  I've tried doing with with `with_only_columns` and it nests the query, which, again, I'd like to avoid

```
>>> print s.with_only_columns(list(s.columns)[::-1])
SELECT name, amount_sum 
FROM (SELECT sum(accounts.amount) AS amount_sum, accounts.name AS name 
FROM accounts GROUP BY accounts.name
 LIMIT :param_1) GROUP BY accounts.name
 LIMIT :param_2
```

#### Edit

To be clear the example above is just an example.  I'm looking for a general solution to do this on arbitrary queries.  Ideally the function would consume a `Select` object and a list of column names in the proper order.

#### Edit 2

Code to create `s`.  Again, I'm looking for a solution to a general problem, not simply a code snippet that fixes the ordering below explicitly.

```
import sqlalchemy

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

t = sqlalchemy.Table('accounts', metadata,
             sqlalchemy.Column('name', sqlalchemy.String),
             sqlalchemy.Column('amount', sqlalchemy.Integer),
             sqlalchemy.Column('id', sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
             )

s = (sqlalchemy.select([sqlalchemy.sql.functions.sum(t.c.amount).label('sum'),    
                         t.c.name])
        .group_by(t.c.name)
        .limit(10))

print s


SELECT sum(accounts.amount) AS sum, accounts.name 
FROM accounts GROUP BY accounts.name
 LIMIT :param_1
```

Comment: Can you post code that creates `Select` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `with_only_columns` but the columns you place into it must come from that list that was sent to the `select()` originally, and *not* the exported columns of the select itself.

You either have to hold onto these columns externally, or get at them via the `select.inner_columns` accessor.

The session below illustrates the various behaviors.  The ".c." collection on any selectable represents "the columns we can SELECT from", which is why using "someselect.c.somecol" implies you're selecting FROM that select statement, just like a table.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import select
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column

>>> t = table('t', column('a'), column('b'), column('c'))

>>> stmt1 = select([t])
>>> print(stmt1)
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c FROM t

>>> print(stmt1.with_only_columns([t.c.b, t.c.a]))
SELECT t.b, t.a FROM t

>>> print(stmt1.with_only_columns([stmt1.c.b, stmt1.c.a]))
SELECT b, a FROM (SELECT t.a AS a, t.b AS b, t.c AS c FROM t)

>>> stmt1_cols = dict((c.key, c) for c in stmt1.inner_columns)

>>> stmt1_cols
{'a': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x102d0e090; a>, 'c': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x102de7c50; c>, 'b': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x10047bb50; b>}

>>> dict(t.c)
{'a': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x102d0e090; a>, 'c': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x102de7c50; c>, 'b': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause at 0x10047bb50; b>}

>>> assert stmt1_cols == dict(t.c)

>>> print(stmt1.with_only_columns([stmt1_cols['b'], stmt1_cols['a']]))
SELECT t.b, t.a FROM t
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found another solution. You may use `inner_columns` property. This property returns iterator to internal variable of `_raw_columns`. It stores original columns that passed to `select` function. 
Some examples:

```
test = Table('test', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),  
    Column('num', Integer, default=0),  
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
statement = select([test]).group_by(test.c.id)
print(statement)
# convert iterator to list
cols = list(statement.inner_columns)
# columns in reverse order
print(statement.with_only_columns(cols[::-1]))
# only some columns
print(statement.with_only_columns([cols[2], cols[0]]))
# convert columns list to ColumnCollection object
columns = ColumnCollection()

for c in cols:
    columns.add(c)

print(statement.with_only_columns([columns.name, columns.id]))
```

To simplify this you may build custom `Select` class, like this:

```
class RearrangeSelect(Select):

    def reverse_columns(self):
        return self.with_only_columns(list(self.inner_columns)[::-1])

    def reorder_columns(self, *args):
        columns = ColumnCollection()

        for c in self.inner_columns:
            columns.add(c)

        query_cols = []
        for name in args:
            c = getattr(columns, name, None)
            if c is None:
                raise ValueError('Bad column name "%s"' % name)

            query_cols.append(c)

        return self.with_only_columns(query_cols)


statement = RearrangeSelect([test]).group_by(test.c.id)
print(statement)
print(statement.reverse_columns())
print(statement.reorder_columns('num', 'name'))
print(statement.reorder_columns('name', 'id'))
```

Full example code [here](https://gist.github.com/bacher09/d7ab8021fc8b3ad0adf0).

Comment: This is great!  I think that the _raw_columns attribute is what I was looking for.

Comment: This isn't public api, so it may change in future. So better access to `inner_columns` property, it returns iterator over `_raw_columns`.

Answer (score 1):

From sqlalchemy [with_only_columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns) manual:

Care should also be taken to use the correct
set of column objects passed to `Select.with_only_columns`.
Since the method is essentially equivalent to calling the
`select` construct in the first place with the given
columns, the columns passed to `.Select.with_only_columns`
should usually be a subset of those which were passed
to the `select` construct, not those which are available
from the `.c` collection of that `select`.  That
is:

```
s = select([table1.c.a, table1.c.b]).select_from(table1)
s = s.with_only_columns([table1.c.b])
```

and **not**:

```
# usually incorrect
s = s.with_only_columns([s.c.b])
```

The latter would produce the SQL:

```
SELECT b
FROM (SELECT t1.a AS a, t1.b AS b
FROM t1), t1
```

**End of documentation**

As you see instead of

```
s.with_only_columns(list(s.columns)[::-1])
```

you should use

```
s.with_only_columns([table.c.name, func.sum(table.c.col2.amount)])
```

As option you may save columns when you create your first `Select` instance and use then
in `with_only_columns` call.

Comment: How would I do this in a more general case where I am passed an arbitrarily complex query and don't necessarily have the original table and construction of columns easily in hand (except for what is available on the original query).  See edit in original question

Comment: As variant you may use hack posted below. Another option is save select fields to some var and later use them again when you need reverse order.

Comment: Can you think of a general solution that does not solve only this problem.  What would you do if I gave you the result query and an ordered list of string column names in preferred order.

Answer (score 1):

As another variant  you can use this hack:

```
def table_cols(columns, table):
    result_columns = []
    for c in columns:
        nc = c.copy()
        nc.table = table
        result_columns.append(nc)

    return result_columns

# now you can do this
s.with_only_columns(table_cols(s.c, your_table)[::-1])
```

`table_cols` functions copies columns from `Select` object and binds then to table, so generated query would use this table.